# RxTx installation on windows java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/io/CommPort

Tags: classpath, java, rxtx

I put `rxtxcomm.jar` into `jre/lib/ext` folder, but I still get `NoClassDefFoundError` Isn't this folder automatically taken into the global classpath?

Thanks

Comment: The only reasonable answer would be that the `JRE` you are running your program with is not the same `JRE` you put the `jar` file in.

Comment: could you post **exception stacktrace**. it is possible that you have put RXTXcomm.jar in the right place, but you hadn't provided the path to the external libraries

Comment: pls see update, you might go better with jssc, depending on you needs

Comment: I have the same problem -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762416/build-issues-rxtx-library-on-wildfly-10-0 .If you resolved yours, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I refactored my project with JSSC and I solved all problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it is taken automatically to classpath, but RXTXcomm uses JNI /native external libraries (.so and .dll files), you must provide the path to them when running your program in command line:

```
java -jar yourprogram.jar -Djava.library.path="PATH_TO_EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES"
```

for linux:

suppose you unpacked the [rxtx.zip](http://rxtx.qbang.org/pub/rxtx/rxtx-2.1-7-bins-r2.zip) to
 /home/user/

if you have 32bit x86 platofrm:

> PATH_TO_EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES = /home/user/Linux/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/

if you have 64bit  x86 platform the it would be:

> PATH_TO_EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES = /home/user/Linux/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/

for windows:

suppose you downloaded and unpacked it to C:\rxtxt

> PATH_TO_EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES = C:\rxtxt\Windows\i368-mingw32\

If you find it cumbersome to do it from command line you can do it from yout code (*before* opening port via RXTXcomm):

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path","PATH_TO_EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES");
```

EDIT:

of course, you must put RXTXcomm.jar in your classpath in addition to all of the above. If running from command line as  jar packaged program - yourprogram.jar - inside the jar you must have a META-INF folder that contains MANIFEST.MF with the following entries:

```
Class-Path: lib/RXTXcomm.jar
Main-Class: pkg.Main
```

and yourprogram.jar must be in folder which has folder lib in which is RXTXcomm.jar, also 
the class with

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

method must be called Main and reside in package named pkg (just replace pkg.Main with whatever you have).

Then you can run your program succesfully and open a serial port if you have one. This approach also eliminates the need to copy anything in jre/lib/ext folder

EDIT^2:

or, if you don't want to pack your program in jar, position yourself in folder which contains the folder pkg and write:

```
java -cp PATH_TO_RXTX/RXTXcomm.jar -Djava.library.path="PATH_TO_EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES" pkg.Main
```

(all paths can be relative or absolute)

EDIT^3:

but I would recommend [Java Simple Serial Connector](http://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/) instead of RXTXcomm:

- it handles heavy load from multiple threads as opposed to RXTXcomm (tested in production)
- external libraries are packed in jar so there is no need for setting java.library.path