# Raspberry pi rxtx java issue

Tags: java

Every time I try to run my **rxtx program** on my raspberry pi, I got this issue:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/io/SerialPortEventListener
```

I installed the rxtx library and still get this issue.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543202/rxtx-installation-on-windows-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-gnu-io-commport - java.library.path must point to where the library is on disk.

Comment: @fvu I tried that but I still get the same issue.

Comment: Managed to fix the issue but now another one popped up: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path